# Has anyone successfully integrated Yet Another Forum 1.9.x with an existing asp.net site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, sqlmembershipprovider, yetanotherforum

I'd like to integrate Yet Another Forum (yafnet) into my asp.net website using the same membership provider as my current website - an out-of-the-box  aspnet sqlmembership provider.  Has anyone done this?  And is it worth the trouble?  The documentation on Yafnet is a bit sparse http://wiki.yetanotherforum.net/AspNetMembershipIntegration.ashx so I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at it a while ago and decided against. The `MembershipProvider` model is screwed up, as with most free ASP.NET products.

It is (or was) impossible to get to use a different provider without it creating users in it's own tables, and possibly doing something odd with auth cookies. They also hadn't used `RoleProvider` or `ProfileProvider` so the whole thing is tightly coupled to their own schema. Not interoperable at all with other applications.

I guess it's fine if you intend to use as is, and you can kind of integrate with another app if your happy to have two copies of the data. For everything negative, I don't know of a single inexpensive ASP.NET forums solution that is any good. This probably isn't the worst.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think I was slowly coming to the same conclusion although the documentation is so sparse it's hard to see what there actually is there to work with.  I don't mind buying a proper product but I've still yet to find one that can authenticate against an existing aspnet membership database.

Comment: [Telligent](http://telligent.com/) (used to be Community Server) is the only one I would recommend but it's expensive, and I haven't used it for a very long time. All free/cheap solutions (I've seen) are pretty bad, and riddled with security problems.

Comment: I'm going to have a look at this one later http://www.jitbit.com/asp-net-forum/.  I have a full vBulletin 4 license but version 4 was so buggy at release that I uninstalled it and vowed never to go near it again.  It's been around two years though and it might be worth revisiting if nothing else pans out.

Comment: Haven't looked at that one before - hopefully a decent alternative.